# "Would" confusion: "it would mean spending more time at home"

Tags: modal-verbs, modality

As per my understanding "would" is used in the situations below:

- Conditional sentences
- Past of will
- Repetition in the past
- Future in the past.

Could someone help me to understand in what category the sentence below falls?

> "For some people, it would mean spending more time at home"

Comment: Some context for the sentence would help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may interpret this as an implicit conditional, in which *it* (whatever it is) is understood from the context to be an optional or contingent or hypothetical eventuality: *(If they did it, doing) it would mean more time at home.*

This is a very common use. Frequently the 'condition' is expressed as a non-finite clause:

> Doing that would be dangerous. 
>   To do that would be dangerous.

Both of these have the sense "If you did that you would expose yourself to danger".